# How to create Django browsable REST API without auth or permissions?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, microservices

I removed `admin`, `auth`, `permissions`, and a few other apps and middleware pieces from my DRF service. I'm running a microservice architecture where each service owns its own database. I don't need Django to pollute all those databases with its own set of `auth`/`user`/`permissions` tables.

Now I'm getting:

```
Model class django.contrib.auth.models.Permission doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

What is still using the `auth` models and how do I get rid of it?

**More Context:**

I want a microservice with only three things:

1. A REST framework
2. A database abstraction layer
3. A browsable API (doesn't have to be HTML, can be pure JSON)

Is it even possible to do such a thing in DRF without having 20 sets of `auth` tables for 20 databases (for 20 services)?

Comment: Did you remove all the middleware?

Comment: Did you set AUTH_USER_MODEL to None?

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `DefaultRouter` made the error go away.